# Image not sent to ecr from codebuild while buildspec has no error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

yaml executed successfully in AWS code build but image not send to aws ecr.
buildspec.yml file output is given below

```
`[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/10/26 09:50:07 Phase context status code:  Message: `
```

Every phase is executed successfully with SUCCEEDED message.
Below is the buildspec.yml file code snippet

```
build:
        commands:
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - echo Building the Docker image...
          - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
          - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Build completed on `date`
          - echo Pushing the Docker images...
          - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
          - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
          - echo Writing image definitions file...
          - printf '[{"name":"ui","imageUri":"%s"}]'    $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
          - cat imagedefinitions.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No command is being run due to bad indentation. Please rectify the indentation using the buildspec reference as guide:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Also I do not see a docker login before the push:

```
- aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

A buildspce sample for Docker is here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html#sample-docker-files